# Should questions with high votes automatically be considered constructive?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, upvotes

I have a question with 15 upvotes, which has been closed as non-constructive. While I can understand that 15 people liking the question may not be enough to consider it useful, how much is? 100 upvotes? 1000? I think for sure a question with 1000 upvotes should never be closed as non-constructive, simply because it is clear that the community finds it valuable.

So, what is the threshold at which the number of upvotes should be taken into account when considering whether a question is constructive or not? Or more broadly, when deciding whether to vote to close a question, should be think of upvotes as being a request not to close it?

Comment: Do you have some examples?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath No, it's just a question that occurred to me, I don't have any particular cases in mind.

Comment: Popularity is not strongly correlated to constructiveness.  The "Programmer cartoon" question was very popular.  It didn't construct anything but some chuckles.

Comment: You need chuckles, it's part of life. To this day may favorite posts are the programmer jokes list, the don't parse with regex rant, stuff like that...

Answer (score 8):

> So, what is the threshold at which the number of upvotes should be taken into account when considering whether a question is constructive or not?

At or above +∞. Votes and "on-topicness" are not related. Popularity is not an indicator of a question being a good fit for the site.

> When deciding whether to vote to close a question, should we think of upvotes as being a request not to close it?

You shouldn't consider the votes on a question when thinking about whether it should be closed or not. You should be evaluating whether the question is a good fit for Stack Overflow, is clear enough, constructive enough, etc. Votes should not be taken into account.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/

Answer (score 0):

Similarly just had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288953/best-version-of-visual-studio-for-native-c-mfc-development-windows-7-and-late) put on hold for having the potential to generate opinion based answers, but found the answers given in the form of comments to be very valuable, and would expect others in a similar situation to find similar value.  Seems a bit draconian.  I think votes do to a degree indicate users find value in a question, and think that should bear to some degree on whether the question should be closed.

Answer (score -3):

*Strictly* following the guidelines, it's clear that the question should be closed.

However, I think this is the *wrong approach*. I think the site belongs just as much to the *community*. If they think the question is important and belongs here, why would you ever close it? We use upvotes as an *indicator* of usefulness and popularity, ignoring it would be silly. Keeping the question open clearly doesn't do any harm.  Live and let live.

Finding the threshold is tough.. I think 100 votes should be enough, but I might be wrong. Maybe a better metric would be overall popularity. If the votes put it in the top 5%, it should be kept open.